# Bounding Expected Value of a piecewise function

Tags: probability-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let X and Y to be two independent random variables with known pdfs. Get a bound for the expected value of the following expression in terms of $E[X]$, $E[Y]$, VAR[X] and VAR[Y]:
\begin{equation}
 g(X,Y) = \biggl\{ \begin{array}{ll}
    x & \mbox{if $y<x$}, \\
    x + (y-x)^b & \mbox{if $x \le y$}. 
    \end{array}
\end{equation}
Where b is a constant between 0 and 1.

If $Z$ has density $f_Z$, then we have $E[f(Z)]=\int f(Z)d\lambda$, and moreover this holds even if $Z$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d > 1$. In particular for $Z=(X,Y)$ we know that $Z$ has density $f_X f_Y$ because $X$,$Y$ are independent. Thus $E[g(Z)] = \int g(z) f_Z(z) dz = \int\int g(x,y)f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy$.
\begin{equation}
\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} g(x,y)f_X(x)f_Y(y) dx dy = \iint_{y<x} x f_X(x)f_Y(y) dxdy + 
\iint_{x \leq y} (x+(y-x)^b)f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy
\end{equation}
Re--writting:
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{array}{ll}
 =  & \int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} xf_X(x)f_Y(y) dx dy + \iint_{x\leq y} (y-x)^b f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy \\
    & \\
 =  & \int_\mathbb{R}E[X]f_Y(y)dy +  \iint_{x\leq y} (y-x)^b f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy \\
    & \\
 =  & E[X]+  \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^y (y-x)^b f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy \\
    & \\
\le & E[X]+  \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^y (y - x)^2 f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy \;\;\;(\mbox{since $(y-x)^b < (y-x)^2$})\\ 
    & \\
 =  & E[X]+  \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^y y^2 f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy - 2\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^y yx f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy + \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^y x^2 f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy \\ 
    & \\
=  & E[X]+  \left(E[Y^2] \int_{-\infty}^y f_X(x)dx - 2E[Y]\int_{-\infty}^y x f_x(x)dx + \int_{-\infty}^y x^2f_x(x)dx \right)\\ 
&\\
\le &  E[X]+  \left(E[Y^2] E[X] - 2E[Y]E[X] + E[X^2]\right)\\
&\\
=  &  E[X]+   E[X]\mbox{VAR}[Y] + E[X]E^2[Y] - 2E[Y]E[X] + \mbox{VAR}[X] + E^2[X]\\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

Don't known whether I'm on the right track..... or whether I can go any further....

Any advice is welcome...